# CISSN vs ISSN-SNS

Tags: nutrition

I've been looking at two sports nutrition certifications:

CISSN: http://www.sportsnutritionsociety.org/CISSN.html

ISSN-SNS: http://www.sportsnutritionsociety.org/SNS.html

They both seem to be offered by the same organisation but I am having a lot of trouble telling what the difference between them is.

What is the difference?